# Extracting specific .json data with python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, typeerror

I have some json data that looks like this:

```
'{"type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [{"id": "0",
               "type": "Feature",
               "properties": {},
               "geometry": {"type": "Polygon",
                            "coordinates": [
                                [[-2.9611591576420615, 53.43052239401445], 
                                 [-2.9602608423579424, 53.43052239401445],
                                 [-2.9602608423579424, 53.4310576043007],
                                 [-2.9611591576420615, 53.4310576043007],
                                 [-2.9611591576420615, 53.43052239401445]]
                             ]}
                }]
   }'
```

I want my code to be able to retrive ONLY the "coordinates" as is and so I tried using this code:

```
points = json_data['features']['geometry']['coordinates']
print(points)
```

However when I run it, I get this error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`
I have tried many things to try and fix this without any success and so I was wondering if anyone knew how I could fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not json, it's a string. You'll need to parse it into an object first.

Comment: `json_data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates']`

Comment: What do you mean by "parsing into an object"?

Comment: Also, @OlvinRoght adding [0] is still giving me a typerror

Comment: `x = json.loads(json_data)`

Comment: @gmgm, it shouldn't if you parsed json string into an object

Comment: Thank You @Barmar! That worked!

Comment: Also @olvinRoght, I soon realized what you meant lol, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON into Python objects.

```
import json

json_data = '''{"type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [{"id": "0",
               "type": "Feature",
               "properties": {},
               "geometry": {"type": "Polygon",
                            "coordinates": [
                                [[-2.9611591576420615, 53.43052239401445], 
                                 [-2.9602608423579424, 53.43052239401445],
                                 [-2.9602608423579424, 53.4310576043007],
                                 [-2.9611591576420615, 53.4310576043007],
                                 [-2.9611591576420615, 53.43052239401445]]
                             ]}
                }]
   }'''
json_obj = json.loads(json_data)
points = json_obj['features']['geometry']['coordinates']
print(points)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close :)

All coordinates

```
['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
```

Targeted coordinates

```
['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0][0]
['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0][1]
['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0][n]
```

But first you need to parse into python dict.

```
with open('data.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
print(data['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
```

Comment: I sort of merged both of your guys' answers. I used  ['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0] to print my data the way I wanted, and I used json_obj = json.loads(json_data) to properly access the data

Comment: @Barmar you should correct your code ['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0]

Comment: Why? What if there are more elements in the list?

Comment: You're not getting the TypeError? Ok, then